# Javascript/jQuery onbeforeunload HTML Event trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, triggers, dojo

I've got this piece of code which isn't doing what I want:

```
$('body').attr("onbeforeunload", "return dojoclick()");

function dojoclick(){
    dojo.byId('jstop').click();
}
```

"Click" function is not working, but If I replace "Click" by "Remove" It works... For example:

```
$('body').attr("onbeforeunload", "return dojoclick()");

function dojoclick(){
    dojo.byId('jstop').remove(); //Element is removed properly
}
```

"Click" function works because If I call "dojoclick()" through console, it triggers:

[image]

Once the button is clicked, It opens a notepad (it calls a Java routine which opens notepad.exe).

Why isn't function `dojoclick()` executing `onbeforeunload`?

Comment: What? Browser opens Notepad?

Comment: Button with id "jstop" has an associated event which calls a Java routine which opens notepad. I just want to trigger that event when the window is closed. I would directly call the function inside the event if i knew how (Dojo does it and i know nothing about Dojo). So the easiest (theorical) way is to simulate a click so the event calls the function.

Notepad is just a test. It indicates that the Java routine is executed.

Comment: Thanks buddy. I was curious about the notepad execution only. I am not sure if I am the right person to answer. All the best with your question.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
              dojoclick();
       });
```

instead of append it as HTML attribute.

or you can directly use

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
              dojo.byId('jstop').click();
       });
```

unfortunately i can't help you more, i really don't know how dojo works

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, perhaps it's quite bad because its functionality:

```
dojo.addOnUnload(function(){
    dojo.byId('jstop').click();
});
```

It works randomly (?) I mean, I close the window 10 times, it triggers 6. I'm hating this.

Comment: I think problem is (maybe) delay time. Add return "something" after click then check again?